# How to make a RMI server work for both local clients (within the same network) and external clients

Tags: java, sockets, networking, rmi, nat

I'm pretty new to Java and RMI, and I decided to try to set up my own server for a chat client on my home computer (just for learning purposes, no real use intended for it) . To sum it up, I'm using a socket connection for messages and RMI for communication between the server and the client . The problem is I'm using a router and I want the client to work both for external connections and internal connections (my laptop for example- connected to the same router as the server).

---

My public ip is: **109.99.33.251** 
My local ip adress is:  **196.168.1.9** 
The problem is that if I set the java.rmi.server.hostname  to

- Server local ip :

  - everything works just as intended, but only when accessing the server from local machines.
  - when accessing from an external machine, only the socket connects , the rmi lookup throws connection refused: connection timed out. (I want to mention that I'm 99% sure the port forwarding is properly set for both the RMI (1099) and the server (5000) )
- Server public ip: everything works, but just for external machines.

  - when trying to connect from a local machine with the local ip of the server the socket connects fine, but the rmiregistry lookup method fails.
  - when connecting from a local machine with the public ip of the server, neither the RMIregistry nor the socket connects.

My guess is that it's a problem with the router. I think it doesnt support [NAT loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback) (Accessing the server from a LAN component with it's public ip) since it never works for me to connect to the server it's public ip from a local machine, even though the port forwarding is set up correctly (it works when connecting externally for both the RMI and socket connections). 
Is there anything I can do to make this work?

 
EDIT: 
On the server side, I set `System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname","109.99.33.251");` just after the server starts and then I:
 `LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);` 



 

 
then i bind the object:

```
MyRemote stub= new Communicator();
registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
registry.bind("comm", stub);
```

where MyRemote is the interface that extends Remote interface and 
Communicator is:

```
public class Communicator extends UnicastRemoteObject implements MyRemote
{
    public Communicator() throws RemoteException
    {
        super(Registry.REGISTRY_PORT);
        System.out.println("I've created the host");
    }
    //the methods in the MyRemote
}`
```

For the sockets i use:

```
ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(5000);
while(true) 
{
    Socket clientSocket = serverSock.accept();
    ClientHandler handler =new ClientHandler(clientSocket);
    clients.add(handler);
    Thread t = new Thread(handler);
    t.start();
    System.out.println("got a connection");
}
```

For the client lookup:
`service=(MyRemote) Naming.lookup("rmi://"+serverIp+"/comm");` 
and for the socket connection `Socket socket=new Socket(serverIp,new Integer(serverPort));`

 `serverIp` holds either the public ip of the server, or the local one, depending on the case i presented earlier. and `serverPort` is 5000

---

To make myself clear, I want the client to work on both local and external machines, so I am looking for a way to bind the remote objects and set up the connections to make both work, if that's possible. 
 
NOTE: I'm sorry, I'm new to networking , java and this site, so please don't mind the mistakes I make when asking questions. Thank you in advance!

FINAL EDIT: I've contacted my ISP about this and they said the router has its latest firmware version and it simply doesn't support NAT loopback.

Comment: Case 2-(b): *when connecting from a local machine with the public ip of the server, neither the RMIregistry nor the socket connects...*. Why should it? And, about the rest - not much can be said without code; security manager/firewall issue appears in case of Connection Timed Out error.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, I addded the code right now. Sorry for the delay, I'm not really used to the formatting requirements of this site. and for case  2- (b) I'm not saying that it should work, I was just presenting my case. I'm all out of ideas on what to do to make it work

Comment: Does the socket connection work with the public IP and port 5000 forwarded? If so it would seem NAT loopback is supported.

Comment: No. Socket connection doesn't work regardless of the java.rmi.server.hostname value if serverIp has the value 109.99.33.251 (the public ip)

Comment: What exception do you get in the failure case? Connect timeout?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I just got back home. `java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect` is the exception I get. Now I see that something doesnt look ok. Shouldn't there be an IP adress in the exception?

Comment: No, but that's the exception I would expect if the NAT isn't doing loopback. Can't imagine why it doesn't: it gives the LAN inside access to every other public IP address on the planet. I would treat it as a defect.

Comment: Thank you. I will contact my ISP and ask about this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the Oracle/Sun RMI implementation is slightly broken in this respect. There is an unnecessary deep assumption that there is a single IP address visible to all clients. You have to set `java.rmi.server.hostname` to the public IP address outside the NAT, and the inside clients have to be able to use that address.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. So indeed, as I suspected it might be a router-related problem. I will request a firmware update for my router from my ISP , because I've read that sometimes a firmware update might include the support of NAT loopback. I'll come back with the results